# How to inline multiple xsd files into one without using include, import or redefine tag?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I have 4 **xsd** files, let's say **A, B, C and D**, **file A imports file B and C, while file B include file D. How can I inline these files so that I only have one xsd file named A containig all B,C and D.**
Is this possible?

**UPDATE**
**SCHEMA TAGS FOR THE FILE**

**FILE A**

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/service/a/msg/v1" xmlns:cst="http://example.com/service/common/v1" xmlns:sd="http://example.com/service/a/data/v1" xmlns:sm="http://example.com/service/a/msg/v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**FILE B**

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/service/common/v1" xmlns:cst="http://example.com/service/common/v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**FILE C**

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/service/common/v1" xmlns:cst="http://example.com/service/common/v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

FILE D

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/service/a/data/v1" xmlns:sd="http://example.com/service/a/data/v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just cut and paste everything that's inside the schema tags from B, C, & D into A. Then remove all the import/includes.

**However** If the schemas contain different targetNamespaces then this approach will not work as you've now put everything in the same targetNamespace. So if your schemas do not share the same targetNamespace then can't combine them (unless they are [chameleon schemas](http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html#design)!)

As you have multiple target namespaces, combining them into a single file is NOT possible. Files B & C could be combined as they share the same targetnamespace, but you would significantly change the schema by combining any of the others.

If you describe the reason you want to combine them, I may be able to help?